# Combining values/keys into one string and printing

Tags: python

[image]

Currently, I have a dictionary and I need to separate the keys and values and then add them together

Here is my code:

```
vowel_count = {"a": 0, "e": 4, "i": 8, "o": 14, "u": 20}
vowels = ""
total = 0
  
# Iterate through vowel_count and get all keys sorted. Combined them into 
# one string and add all values. Print out the combined string and the 
total value.

for vowel, count in vowel_count.items():
    print(vowel)
    print(count)
```

Comment: The comment provided in the problem should help you - "combine them into one string"

Comment: @pecey Im not sure how to do that

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_concatenation.asp) should help you.

Comment: See this links, they would help: [How to sort a string alphabetically in Python](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-sort-a-string-alphabetically-in-python), [Python Concatenate String and int](https://www.journaldev.com/23642/python-concatenate-string-and-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- strings can be combined, concatenated, with `+` and integers can be summed with `+`

  - [Splitting, Concatenating, and Joining Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/)
- a object can be updated with `+=`

  - Where `i=1`, `i += 1` now `i` is 2
  - Where `v='a'`, `v += 'b'` now `v` is 'ab'

```py
vowel_count = {"a": 0, "e": 4, "i": 8, "o": 14, "u": 20}

l = ''
i = 0
for k, v in vowel_count.items():
    l += k
    i += v

print(l)
'aeiou'

print(i)
46
```